# PHP - populating array with increasing number

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to populate an array with the results of a for loop. Not really sure if I'm using the correct loop, anyway I'll just show you what I'm trying to do.

```
$voucher= array();
for ($x = $numero; $x < ($quantita+$numero); $x++){
    $voucher[$quantita]=$numero[$x];
    echo "$voucher <br/>";
}
```

`$numero` and `$quantita` are numbers.

What I'm trying to do is taking `$numero`, adding `$quantita` and creating an array which is every number between `$numero` and `$numero+$quantita`. Then I'll have to add these numbers to a DB.

I hope I've explained it well enough for you to understand (not sure tho).

Comment: Can you add var_dump() of $quantita and $numero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

You could do:

```
$voucher = range($numero,$numero+$quantita);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($voucher,TRUE).'</pre>';
```

Nothing more, that's all.

I think you went wrong here:

```
$voucher[$quantita]=$numero[$x];
```